# Why dio posts empty form data?

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I have a function to upload an image but the server does not receive anything and I get 500 status code. I'm sure that the server is fine. It works when I send a post request from the postman!
This is my function:

```
uploadPrescriptionToAll(File file, data) async {

  String convertedFilePath = await convertImage(file);

   String token = await getToken();

   Response response;
   Dio dio = Dio();
   dio.options.baseUrl = "http://x.x.x.x:x";

   FormData formData = FormData.from({
     "image":
         UploadFileInfo(new File(convertedFilePath), "image.jpg"),
     "data": data,
   });
   try {
     response = await dio.post("/api/images",
         data: formData,
         options: Options(headers: {
           "Authorization": token,
           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
         }));
   } catch (e) {
     print("Error Upload: " + e.toString());
   }
   print("Response Upload:" + response.toString());
}
```

how can I post the file (form-data) correctly? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the Options method?

Comment: Have you tried the full URL in the post method instead of using options? dio.post('http : //x.x.x.x:x/api/images',...

Answer (score 6):

Using **Dio** It's very simple by using  :  **FormData.fromMap()**

```
searchCityByName(String city) async {
     Dio dio = new Dio(); 
    var a = {"city": city};
    var res = await dio.post(apiSearchState, data:FormData.fromMap(a));
  }
```

Comment: is 'apiSearchState' is complete url for the api? I'm exactly doing this but body goes empty for FormData.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should pass a `Map<String, dynamic>` object to `dio.post()`'s `data` field. For example:

```
response = await dio.post("/api/images",
     data: {"image": "image.jpg", "data": data});
```

See: https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/88 for details